# Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 269 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a basic skeleton of spring boot on app engine standard environment with runtime as java11.

my app.yaml has the following entries

```
runtime: java11
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 100
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
env_variables:
 GAE_ENV: "standard"
entrypoint: java -noverify -jar myserver-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

when I deploy the app using app.yaml or jar file, the app gets deployed but I get following error.

> Exceeded soft memory limit of 256 MB with 269 MB after servicing 0
> requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

I upgraded my instance from F1 to F4, but I am getting the same error. There isn't much code or work in my app, it's just a plane spring boot app with all libraries like cloud SQL, spring security. But from functionality point of view, there is nothing in app.

I am also attaching other INFO I'm getting in google cloud logs

> This request caused a new process to be started for your application,
> and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time.
> This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical
> request for your application.
>
> While handling this request, the process that handled this request was
> found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely
> to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your
> application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory
> leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient
> memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sandeepapplabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysalesbuddyserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Sales Buddy</name>
    <description>My Sales Buddy server project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.3.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>

                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>mysalesbuddy3</projectId>
                    <version>1</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: If you upgrade from F1 to F4, you would not get the same error message. This means you did not upgrade. Go back over your deployment steps.

Comment: how to check which instance my app is deployed on? I checked the app engine dashboard and the according to billing price, I think it's getting deployed to F4. And as I'm deploying with app.yaml which says F4, shouldn't it get to deploy to F4 only?

Comment: This is what I found from instance details from cloud console runtime: java11
env: standard
instance_class: F4
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
env_variables:
  GAE_ENV: standard
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: 0.030s
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  max_instances: 100
network: {}

Answer (score 0):

Even if your application isn't consuming many resources, it's possible that the VM plus all the services running are consuming them.

The solution as mentioned in the logs is to switch into a larger instance.

If you have already deployed a new version with a larger instance I recommend to verify that this is the version dispatching all the traffic, you can do that by going into App Engine -> [versions](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions/), and verify that the traffic allocation is 100% so you can make sure that all the traffic is going through the last version.

Comment: I checked that, all traffic is going to latest deployed version

Comment: could you try to add the -Xmx flag on the entrypoint? Probably with -Xmx64m could be enough to limit the amount of memory the jvm is using